# Can't get a 200 response from an API performing a post using the locustio

Tags: python, locust

I am using Locust to try and perform a load test. I can't get a good (200) response from the API we are using. It continually gives me a:

```
{
  "message": "Invalid API key",
  "status": 400
}
```

However, using the same information I am using for Locust in Postman generates a proper response. The post is a cross site post so it's not going to the host defined for locust. I have replaced any sensitive info with Redacted. So what am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated.

Code Example:

```
targetURL = 'https://Redacted, name=https:Redacted'

searchBody1 = {"params": "facets=%5B%22Property%20Type%22%2C%22amenities.Property%20Amenities%22%2C%22amenities.Suitability%22%2C%22amenities.Area%20Activities%22%2C%22Bedrooms%22%2C%22Total%20Beds%22%2C%22Bathrooms%22%5D&hitsPerPage=0"}

searchHeader1 = {'Host': 'Redacted',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Length': '223',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Origin': 'Redacted',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SM-G930U) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.93 Mobile Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Referer': 'Redacted',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'}

response = self.client.post(url=targetURL, json=searchBody1, headers=searchHeader1, catch_response=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the url parameter to literally be 'https://Redacted, name=https:Redacted'. Python will not expand that to mean two different parameters, as you seem to have assumed.

You should specify name as an independent parameter in the call to post(), like this:

```
self.client.post(url='https://Redacted', name='your_short_name', ...)
```